# pandas to_json changes date format to "epoch time"

Tags: python, pandas, flask

whenever i convert dataFrame to_json any date format changes to "**epoch time**"

`[{"idNo":1234567891012,"Name":"Jack","genderType":"male","Date":1544572800000,"branchName":"NY","location":"loc1","pCode":123}]`
Original date was
`Date:2018-12-12`

my python code

```
@app.route("/fileviewer/" , methods=["GET" , "POST"])
def fileviewer(name):
dest = (file_destination)
df = pd.read_excel(dest)
print(df)
x1=df.to_json(orient ='records')
print(x1)
render_template('fileviewer.html',x=df.to_html())
return render_template('fileviewer.html',x=x1)
```

`df` prints fine

`x1` prints with the "epoch time"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the format using the option `date_format`:

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame([
    {'A' : 0, 't' : datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 2)},
    {'A' : 1, 't' : datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 5)},
    {'A' : 2, 't' : datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 7)}
])
>>> df.to_json(date_format = 'iso')
'{"A":{"0":0,"1":1,"2":2},"t":{"0":"2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z","1":"2018-01-05T00:00:00.000Z","2":"2018-01-07T00:00:00.000Z"}}'
```

Comment: so in my case df.to_json(orient ='records',date_format = 'iso')?

Comment: it worked but it add time to it :S , i don't need to add a time stamp here.`2018-12-12T00:00:00.000Z`

Comment: is it possible to get just a plain date without the timestamp?

Comment: @SujayDSa How do you mean?

Comment: @caverac when do a to_json it converts 2018-01-05 to 2018-01-05T00:00:00.000Z. So I am forced to convert my date to a string separately and then do a to_json

Comment: @SujayDSa I see, no, it is not necessary, if you have the date as a string in the format you want, you wouldn't need to use this option

Comment: @caverac the problem is my date is in datetime format.

Comment: @SujayDSa Which format do you want to be your output to be?

Answer (score 0):

I found a great solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149588/change-in-date-from-string-to-datetime-object-when-converting-pandas-dataframe-t)

```
df.assign(
    **df.select_dtypes(['datetime']).astype(str).to_dict('list')
).to_json(orient="records")
```