# How to change datetime format while converting df to to_json using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

While reading sql query pandas dataframe showing correct date and timestamp format. but while converting df to json using pd.to_json date and timestamp format showing wrong format.

```
import json
from ast import literal_eval
sql_data = pd.read_sql_query(''' select * from sample_table ''',con)
sql_data

tabId   tab_int tab_char    tab_decimal tab_date    tab_timestamp
1       100     test5        99.54      2021-08-16  2021-08-16 23:30:48
2        20     test1       85.24       2021-08-16  2021-08-16 23:31:10

json_data = sql_data.to_json(orient="records", date_format='iso')

Output : 
[{"tabId":1,"tab_int":100,"tab_char":"test5","tab_decimal":99.54,"tab_date":"2021-08-16T00:00:00.000Z","tab_timestamp":"2021-08-16T23:30:48.000Z"},{"tabId":2,"tab_int":20,"tab_char":"test1","tab_decimal":85.24,"tab_date":"2021-08-16T00:00:00.000Z","tab_timestamp":"2021-08-16T23:31:10.000Z"}]

Expected Output format like :
[{"tabId":1,"tab_int":100,"tab_char":"test5","tab_decimal":99.54,"tab_date":"2021-08-16","tab_timestamp":"2021-08-16 23:30:48"},{"tabId":2,"tab_int":20,"tab_char":"test1","tab_decimal":85.24,"tab_date":"2021-08-16","tab_timestamp":"2021-08-16 23:31:10"}]
```

If I know the columns name means I can able to achieve using below method before converting to json.

```
sql_data['tab_timestamp'] = sql_data['tab_timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

But, I need to read data from random tables and wants to convert that. That time I don't know which is the right column. Request you to please give any suggestion for this.

Comment: can you check on the PR, like `df.assign(**df.select_dtypes(['datetime']).astype(str).to_dict('list') ).to_json(orient="records")`
 [more is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149588/change-in-date-from-string-to-datetime-object-when-converting-pandas-dataframe-t)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an Open PR for this issue which is still Open [No way with to_json to write only date out of datetime](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16492).

May be one thing which you could try:

```
sql_data.to_json(orient='records', date_format='iso', date_unit='s')
```

Comment: checked, its showing wrong format only "tab_timestamp":"2021-08-16T23:31:10Z"